# How to get network activity from Java applet?

Tags: java, browser, applet

I have a third-party Java applet that is loaded via browser and make some network activity (don't know what exactly, maybe http requests, maybe https).

How would i sniff/trace that activity?
I just need requests headers, not it's content.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is basic sniffing and is not related to neither java nor applets. [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is a perfect tool for the job. You may also use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) (Windows only) or something similar to investigate http(s) activities with more detail.